# How can I configure Okular to save annotations in the pdf file by default?

Tags: kde, pdf, kde4, okular

As far as I know, Okular annotation are stored locally in `/home/user/.kde/share/apps/okular/docdata`.

However, there are many cases where I need the annotations to be saved within the pdf file itself (e.g. sharing with others, syncing between machines). In these cases, I can save the annotations to the pdf file itself using `Save As...`.

But how can I configure Okular to save annotations within the pdf file (as it does with `Save As...` **by default and automatically, without having to `Save As...`**?

Answer (score 0):

Update to Okular >= 1.3 (shipped with KDE Applications >= 17.12)